# WebSocket connection delay without localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, delay, lag

I'm developing a WebApp in a company using WebSockets. It's currently in a basic "client sends message, server responds"-state and works just as it's supposed to work... under localhost that is.

I'm using a Tomcat 7 and Netbeans to deploy the app. So basically I reach it under

> localhost:8080/WebApp

and the WebSocket itself is referenced as

> var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketTest/WsSendTest");

If I now change the "localhost" to my Network IP I can still reach the Website, but the functionality seems broken. I have a "ping" button that sends a ping-msg to the server. If I rapidly click on that the functionality seems to be restored. But after F5-ing it's broken again.

It only seem to happen when I change the ws:// path to my IP.

Weird thing is, the onOpen()-method is implemented in a way, that it logs the session-ID of any client connecting to the WebSocket and it recognizes the connection immediately. Just the rest seems to "lag" or "block"?

I will end up having to use the IP since other ppl in the network can't rech the ws:// if it's set on localhost in the webpage.

Can anyone relate?

Comment: You need to identify where issue happens in first place, as you described problem but it is not enough as your back-end (Java) might be a problem area.
Do some debugging and understand list of events that occur first, and then narrow down issue are. If wont solve it already by that, come then and ask specific problem.
Now it is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I removed all extra code and started with adding all the basic @On methods and it somehow worked in the end, though I didn't change anything... Maybe the tomcat just needed a restart.. *sigh

Comment: So it all works now?
I've told you that you will be able to "solve" it just by debugging or simplification.
That is usually a good way to start.
If you think question should be removed, could you please comment that in head of question that you wish to remove it?

Comment: Author has been able to solve his problems (check in comments) and it wasn't any particular problem or it wont relate to question.

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve this issue. I have exact same issue. My chat is working with ws://localhost but not with public ip address. It says - WebSocket connection to 'ws://My_elastic_ip:8080/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200.

Comment: If you solved the issue please add the solution as an answer and accept it